# Can Cucumber prompt for input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, cucumber, bdd

Is it possible to prompt the user for input while running a Cucumber feature?

For example, I'm adding a feature for user authentication in a Rails app, but since authentication will be happening through an external service, I can't set up a dummy account for the purposes of the test.

My initial plan was to simply prompt the user for a username and password to use during the test, but Cucumber doesn't seem to like doing that in a step definition.

I know that this would make automated testing more difficult, but I'm not sure how else to include this authentication feature.  Is there a way to get user input, or is there another approach that uses mocks that would work better?  Alternatively, are there ways to pass arbitrary arguments to use in the step definitions at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about using mocks but it seems like if you need an environment-specific user account for testing, you should be using environment variables:

```
$ SOME_USERNAME=foo SOME_PASSWORD=bar rake test:features
```

Then in your code:

```
foo = MyAwesomeFooClass.new(ENV["SOME_USERNAME"], ENV["SOME_PASSWORD"])
```

**Edit:** Now that I think about it, you should almost certainly not be hitting a real API from your tests.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. You could then make the test fail if the environment variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Exactly. I'm actually working on a gem at the moment that makes it easier to manage ENV variables. http://github.com/bloudermilk/hood (very early in development).

Comment: Ah, your edit hits a good point. The fun part is figuring out how to mock it out...

Comment: @bloudermilk What would you do if that password was particularly sensitive and you didn't want it in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the VCR gem to record the interaction with the external service and play it back for subsequent test runs:

https://www.relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr

Comment: That'd be nice if I were using a pure HTTP API - I'm most likely going to be using LDAP authentication.  I'd rather not be tied to an authorization technique just for the specs.  In addition, it would still need to store my credentials, which is unacceptable in this case.